# Weka trees, which one supports STRING attribute?

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree

I am trying to train a model. My dataset is like :

```
@RELATION thesis 
@attribute paragraph  string
@ATTRIBUTE class     {computer,civil engineering,biology} 

@DATA 
'This is related to computer science', computer
'This is science to computer science', computer
'This is related to computer science', computer
'biology data and all about medical', biology
'organs and body data and all about medical', biology
'tissues and diseases data and all about medicine, surgery and tissues', biology
'fighting against diseases data and all about cells and blood', biology
```

I have tried J48, RandomForester and ADTREE trees. None of them supports `STRING` attributes.

```
weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree: Cannot handle string attributes!
```

Do we have any tree that supports STRING attribute???

My code is working all okay when I use `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the StringToNominal filter before training. You find it in unsupervised->attribute->StringToNominal

Comment: cli or the gui but you can also apply the filter in the api.
the fqcn is: weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal

Comment: I see, I will check how to use it against attributes while training